# iOS Charts add legend text

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

I created a bubble chart with iOS Charts that has three different colors. Now I want to add a legend for every color. The little colored squares for the legend already show up but the text doesn't.
That is how I tried to add the legend text, is there anything wrong with that or is something missing?

```
let firstLegend = LegendEntry.init(label: "Below 50", form: .default, formSize: CGFloat.nan, formLineWidth: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashPhase: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashLengths: nil, formColor: UIColor.black)
let secondLegend = LegendEntry.init(label: "Between 50 and 75", form: .default, formSize: CGFloat.nan, formLineWidth: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashPhase: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashLengths: nil, formColor: UIColor.black)
let thirdLegend = LegendEntry.init(label: "Over 75", form: .default, formSize: CGFloat.nan, formLineWidth: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashPhase: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashLengths: nil, formColor: UIColor.black)

bubbleView.legend.entries = [firstLegend, secondLegend, thirdLegend]
```

Comment: Hi am using above code to display the legend entries,but texts are overlapping with each other?is there any solution?

Comment: @ShilpashreeMC I am also facing same overlapping issue, were you able to solve it?

Comment: I had to use `bubbleView.setCustom(entries: [firstLegend, secondLegend, thirdLegend])` to get custom legend to appear.  This doesn't fix the overlap issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Set this in the code, it will not accept custom legend otherwise**

isLegendCustom = true

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing wrong. The only reason is that one Legend object only stores one legend label color.

```
open var textColor = NSUIColor.black
```

A LegendEntry object doesn't have a label color property.
So, you can't set labels in one legend to different colors unless you customize a sub class of `LegendRenderer.swift`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this, it'll work.

```
let firstLegend = LegendEntry.init(label: "Below 50", form: .default, formSize: CGFloat.nan, formLineWidth: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashPhase: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashLengths: nil, formColor: UIColor.black)
let secondLegend = LegendEntry.init(label: "Between 50 and 75", form: .default, formSize: CGFloat.nan, formLineWidth: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashPhase: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashLengths: nil, formColor: UIColor.black)
let thirdLegend = LegendEntry.init(label: "Over 75", form: .default, formSize: CGFloat.nan, formLineWidth: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashPhase: CGFloat.nan, formLineDashLengths: nil, formColor: UIColor.black)


chartView.legend.setCustom(entries: [firstLegend, secondLegend, thirdLegend])
```